# If Confucius was alive and started a modern school today, what would it look like practically?

Tags: education, confucius

Peace and Blessings.  Recently I have been researching ancient practices in regards to teaching.  One of such that I came across was [Confucius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius#Philosophy) and his approach to [education](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.2202/1940-1639.1045#:%7E:text=Confucius%20revolutionized%20education%20by%20providing,an%20education%20should%20be%20educated.).  I am not well versed in Philosophy nor [Confucianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucianism) but his emphasis on character development and love for humanity is beautiful. My question is if Confucious was alive during this age/time, was a principal, headmaster, or superintendent, how would his school or district look during these days? What would the pedagogy look like and be?  How would teachers be selected and/or trained?  Are there formal schools today that adheres to his teachings and if so where? Articles, book references, personal insight, etc are all welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I doubtful how much sense this makes. Confucius was a thinker of his time, the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_Age

Comment: @CriglCragl Peace and Blessings. May you explain and unpack your reference, please?

Comment: Are you asking how would Confucious go about teaching, or what would Confucious be teaching about?